# how to convert numbers into words while keeping leading zeros?

Tags: python, numbers, words

is there a way to turn numbers, ether in a string, or an int, into words without loosing leading zero's? I'm trying to convert dates and times and phone numbers into words, but the second I convert the string value into an int I lose my leading zeros.

here is my code right now for doing the number to words, and it works great as long as there are no leading zeros. here's an example of my problem...
let's say I'm turning a date 08-02-2004 I wan't this to output as zero eight zero two... etc
but for me to do that in it's current state I would have to do some round about methods... unless I'm missing something.

```
units = ["", "one", "two", "three", "four",  "five", 
    "six", "seven", "eight", "nine "]
teens = ["", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen",  "fourteen", 
    "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"]
tens = ["", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty",
    "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]
thousands = ["","thousand", "million",  "billion",  "trillion", 
    "quadrillion",  "quintillion",  "sextillion",  "septillion", "octillion", 
    "nonillion",  "decillion",  "undecillion",  "duodecillion",  "tredecillion", 
    "quattuordecillion",  "sexdecillion",  "septendecillion",  "octodecillion", 
    "novemdecillion",  "vigintillion "]

def numToWords(self, num):
    words = []
    if num == 0:
        words.append("zero")
    else:
        numStr = "%d" % num
        numStrLen = len(numStr)
        groups = (numStrLen + 2) / 3
        numStr = numStr.zfill(groups * 3)
        for i in range(0, groups*3, 3):
            h = int(numStr[i])
            t = int(numStr[i+1])
            u = int(numStr[i+2])
            g = groups - (i / 3 + 1)

            if h >= 1:
                words.append(units[h])
                words.append("hundred")

            if t > 1:
                words.append(tens[t])
                if u >= 1:
                    words.append(units[u])
            elif t == 1:
                if u >= 1:
                    words.append(teens[u])
                else:
                    words.append(tens[t])
            else:
                if u >= 1:
                    words.append(units[u])

            if g >= 1 and (h + t + u) > 0:
                words.append(thousands[g])
    return ' '.join([w for w in words])
```

any help or suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many leading zeros do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're supplying a string in the first place and only evaluate as an int when you have to. E.g.:

```
def numToWords(self, numStr):
    words = []
    if int(numStr) == 0:
        words.append("zero")
    else:
        # no longer needed, it's already a string
        # numStr = "%d" % num
        numStrLen = len(numStr)
        groups = (numStrLen + 2) /
        ...
```

Comment: thanks man this was a huge help... I just had to figure out how many leading zeros there where by doing a simple calculation: here's that code.     
`numStrLen = len(numStr)
    numintStr = len(str(int(numStr)))
    
    # if thre is a diffrence then that's how many leading zero's I need to append. 
    diff = numStrLen - numintStr
    if diff > 0:
        for i in range(diff):
            words.append('zero')`

worked like a charm. again thank you very much! I replaced the if int(numStr) == 0 and replaced it with the above code.

Answer (score 1):

When you format your int into a string using %d, it drops any leading zeros. To keep them, you need to specify a minimum number of digits, like this:

```
numStr = "%03d" % num
```

This will append leading zeros to any number that has less than 3 digits (making the minimum number of digits 3, in this case). But before you go slapping on leading zeros willy-nilly, you first need to decide how many total digits you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution using recursive approach ?

```
def numToWords(i):
    if i < 20:
        result = 'zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,\
                  seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,\
                  thirteen,fourteen,fifteen,sixteen,\
                  seventeen,eighteen,nineteen'.split(',')[i]
    elif i < 100:
        result = ',,twenty,thirty,forty,fifty,sixty,seventy,\
                    eighty,ninety'.split(',')[i//10]
        if i % 10:
            result += ' ' + numToWords(i % 10)
    elif i < 1000:
        result = checkio(i // 100) + ' hundred'
        if i % 100:
            result += ' ' + numToWords(i % 100)
    return result
```